# Help with my simple javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript

I have an id #navigation li a and a class .menu-description . I want to change class from .menu-description to .menu-descriptionnew whenever user hovers on #navigation li a

My jquery so far:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navigation li a').onmouseover(function() {

  //Check if element with class exists, if so change it to new
           if ($('div.menu-description').length != 0)
                $('div.menu-description').removeClass('menu-description').addClass('menu-descriptionnew');
           //Check if element with class 'menu-descriptionnew' exists, if so change it to 'menu-description'
           else if ($('div.menu-descriptionnew').length != 0)
                $('div.menu-descriptionnew').removeClass('menu-descriptionnew').addClass('menu-description');
                });
});
</script>
```

But it's not working. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery event is "[mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)" not "onmouseover"

You could clean up your code a lot with the use of [**.toggleClass() method**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) and the [**.hover() event**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

[**Here's a simple example**](http://jsfiddle.net/PXU2w/)

Comment: It works like this http://jsfiddle.net/PXU2w/3/ But if I put "li a" everywhere near #navigation the background disappears and it stops working. Can you suggest any tips how to avoid this? Thanks.

Comment: The background disappears? The link that you sent me doesn't have that affect in it

Comment: are you sure you want the class to change when you hover over the link? you may want it to switch classes when you hover over the list item